# Casting Component to JPanel always null

Tags: java, swing

I have problem and I havent been able to find a solution.
This is my code for adding tabs:

```
protected void addTab(File file, String tooltip) {
        if(alreadyOpened(file)) return;
        MyPanel panel = new MyPanel(file);

        tabbedPane.addTab(file.getName(), loadIconFrom("icons/save_green.png"), panel, tooltip);
        tabbedPane.setSelectedComponent(panel);
    }
```

And this is my code in which I check if tab is already opened(containing same file) and if so return true.

```
private boolean alreadyOpened(File file) {
        boolean flag = false;
        int count = tabbedPane.getTabCount();

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            MyPanel panel = (MyPanel) tabbedPane.getTabComponentAt(i);
            // if(panel == null) continue;  If I add this line of code tabs are added normaly, but with unwanted duplicates
            flag = panel.hasFile(file); //checks if new file contained in selected panel(added through constructor)
        }

        return flag;
    }
```

The problem is when I open file it creates new tab, but if i try to open that same file again, program throws null pointer exception and this part is selected

```
flag = panel.hasFile(file);
```

So I am wondering why is my panel null, if it obviously already exists?
Thanx in advance.

Comment: If something is `null` after the cast, the input to the cast was `null`. In your case you should investigate what `tabbedPane.getTabComponentAt` actually does (maybe `i` is wrong?).

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    MyPanel panel = (MyPanel) tabbedPane.getTabComponentAt(i);
    if(panel == null) continue; 
    flag = panel.hasFile(file); //checks if new file contained in selected panel(added through constructor)
    if (flag) break;
 }
```

Try the code above. In your case you in fact erase the flag value with with the last tab component's `hasFile(file)` call.

Check how many real nulls in the loop. All? Just one?

If all you may use wrong instance. Tabs are added to one instance but you check another one.

Answer (score 0):

I should have used `getComponentAt(i)` instead `getTabComponentAt(i)`.